# Create a calendar without module by Python

Tags: python

I have an error after I run the code below.
I don't think I did anything wrong, but still get the breakdown.
The error is like it. Does anyone know the reason? Thank you.

Traceback (most recent call last):
line 46, in print_calendar
number = monthdays[month]
KeyError: 11

```
def print_calendar(month, year):
# Set up the dictionary
months = {1:'January', 2:'February', 3:'March', 4:'April', 5:'May', 6:'June',7:'July',8:'August',
          9:'September', 10:'October', 11:'November', 12:'December'}
monthdays = {'January':31, 'March':31, 'April':30, 'May':31, 'June':30, 'July':31, 'August':31,
             'September':30, 'October':31, 11:30, 'December':31}
month = int(month)
year = int(year)
# Calculate the leap year
if (year % 4) == 0 and (year % 100) != 0 or (year % 400) == 0:
    monthdays = {'February':29}
else:
    monthdays = {'February':28}

# Using Zeller's congruence
# Change in year if month is January or February
if 1 <= month <= 2:
    year -= 1
# Switch months so that March becomes the first month of the year,
# and January/ February become the 11th and 12th months respectively
# Convert variables to algorithm variables (so a = month and b = day)
if month < 3:
    a = month + 10
else:
    a = month - 2
b = 1   # The first day of the month
c = year % 100
d = year // 100
# Compute starting weekdays with algorithm
w = (13 * a - 1) // 5
x = c // 4
y = d // 4
z = w + x + y + b + c - 2 * d
r = z % 7
r = (r + 7) % 7

# Print the title
space = ' '
print(space*4 + months[month]+space+str(year))
print("Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa")

# Print out the calendar
number = monthdays[month]
start_days = r
for i in range(1, number+1):
    if i == 1:
        print((space * 3) * start_days, end='')
    if i < 10:
        print('', i, end=' ')
    elif i >= 10:
        print(i, end=' ')
    if (i + start_days) % 7 == 0:
        print('\n', end='')
print_calendar('11', '2020')
```

Comment: in `monthdays` for `'November'` you have specified `11`... Rest all are months in string format...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line could be a problem,

`monthdays = {'February':29}`

You're setting `monthdays` to `{'February': 29}` so if you try to access a different month than February, you'll get a KeyError.

If you want to only change the value for `February`, replace it with
`monthdays['February'] = 29`.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't notice it.

Answer (score 2):

`monthdays = {'February':29}` and `monthdays = {'February':28}` overwrite the initial contents of `monthdays`.

To add a new key to a dictionary, use `monthdays['February'] = 29`.

Answer (score 2):

You had a few errors in your code.

1. November was specified incorrectly in "monthdays" ("11" instead of "November")
2. When specifying "february" you were overwriting your monthdays dictionary
3. You need to write `number = monthdays[months[month]]`

Corrected code:

```py
def print_calendar(month, year):
    # Set up the dictionary
    months = {1: 'January', 2: 'February', 3: 'March', 4: 'April', 5: 'May', 6: 'June', 7: 'July', 8: 'August',
              9: 'September', 10: 'October', 11: 'November', 12: 'December'}
    monthdays = {'January': 31, 'March': 31, 'April': 30, 'May': 31, 'June': 30, 'July': 31, 'August': 31,
                 'September': 30, 'October': 31, 'November': 30, 'December': 31}
    month = int(month)
    year = int(year)
    # Calculate the leap year
    if (year % 4) == 0 and (year % 100) != 0 or (year % 400) == 0:
        monthdays['February'] = 29
    else:
        monthdays['February'] = 28

    # Using Zeller's congruence
    # Change in year if month is January or February
    if 1 <= month <= 2:
        year -= 1
    # Switch months so that March becomes the first month of the year,
    # and January/ February become the 11th and 12th months respectively
    # Convert variables to algorithm variables (so a = month and b = day)
    if month < 3:
        a = month + 10
    else:
        a = month - 2
    b = 1  # The first day of the month
    c = year % 100
    d = year // 100
    # Compute starting weekdays with algorithm
    w = (13 * a - 1) // 5
    x = c // 4
    y = d // 4
    z = w + x + y + b + c - 2 * d
    r = z % 7
    r = (r + 7) % 7

    # Print the title
    space = ' '
    print(space * 4 + months[month] + space + str(year))
    print("Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa")

    # Print out the calendar
    number = monthdays[months[month]]
    start_days = r
    for i in range(1, number + 1):
        if i == 1:
            print((space * 3) * start_days, end='')
        if i < 10:
            print('', i, end=' ')
        elif i >= 10:
            print(i, end=' ')
        if (i + start_days) % 7 == 0:
            print('\n', end='')


print_calendar('11', '2020')
```

Answer (score 1):

`monthday` is a dictionary where the monthnames are the keys but you try to get the value via an int index (`month`).

You should instead use the line:

```
number = monthdays[months[month]]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you entered 11 as a key, you entered it as an Integer and when you try to reference it you look at it as a String.

you need to pay attention to the different types, you have two options:

1. change the key in the dictionary to be a string instead of an int
2. change the way you reference the key from a string to an int